# undefined method `appointments_path' using nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a  nested resource `appointments` in `profiles` in `route.rb`.

```
resources :profiles, only: [:show, :update, :edit] do
 resources :appointments
end
```

In my `AppointmentsController.rb` I write new method like this

```
   def new
    @appointment = Appointment.new
   end
```

I have form for this `new` method in `appointments/new.html.erb`

```
   <section class="login-page border-top-blue padding-v-10">
    <section class="login-details-div bg-light-grey">

    <%= form_for(@appointment, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal login-form-container login-form-div' }) do |f| %>

    <h1>Create New Appointments</h1>

    <div class="form-div-send-for-inlinement-icon-with-text-field">
    <span class="form-wrapper ">
        <i class="fa fa-user login-icon-white login-icon-envelop "></i>
    </span>
      <div class="label-input-div input-width">
        <label for="" class="login-label-div"></label>
        <div class="form-wrapper"><%= f.text_area :description, class:'login-icon-white', autofocus: true %></div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="form-div-send-for-inlinement-icon-with-text-field">
    <span class="form-wrapper ">
        <i class="fa fa-envelope login-icon-white login-icon-envelop "></i>
    </span>
      <div class="label-input-div input-width">
        <label for="" class="login-label-div">topic</label>
        <div class="form-wrapper"><%= f.text_field :topic, class:'login-icon-white' %></div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="form-div-send-for-inlinement-icon-with-text-field">
    <span class="form-wrapper ">
        <i class="fa fa-envelope login-icon-white login-icon-envelop "></i>
    </span>
      <div class="label-input-div input-width">
        <label for="" class="login-label-div">Appointment Date</label>
        <div class="form-wrapper"><%= f.date_field :appointment_date, class:'login-icon-white' %></div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="form-div-send-for-inlinement-icon-with-text-field">
    <span class="form-wrapper ">
        <i class="fa fa-envelope login-icon-white login-icon-envelop "></i>
    </span>
      <div class="label-input-div input-width">
        <label for="" class="login-label-div">class hours</label>
        <div class="form-wrapper"><%= f.number_field :class_hours, class:'login-icon-white' %></div>
      </div>

    </div>



    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="" class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10 col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-10 col-md-offset-1 col-md-11 login-btn-div">

        <%= f.submit "submit", :class => "login-btn" %>
      </label>
      <label for="" class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10 col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-10 col-md-offset-1 col-md-11 login-btn-div">

        <%= link_to "Cancel", root_path(), :class => "login-btn" %>
      </label>
    </div>

  <% end %> 
   </section>
    </section>
```

I have a link tag in `profiles/show.html.erb` for callling this new method of `AppointmentsController.rb` .

```
      <%= link_to "book a class", new_profile_appointment_path, class: 'btn-green2' %>
```

I don't understand why whenever I click this link I got link in url

```
http://localhost:3000/profiles/3/appointments/new
```

which is I need.But there is an error
 `undefined method 'appointments_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f24ccc16bf8>:0x007f24ccc154b0>`

I could not figure out my fault here.Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using nested resources for creating every appointment you need a profile under which your appointment will be nested. So you need to pass `profile_id` under which your appointment will be created as your path `new_profile_appointment_path` is also saying.

```
<%= form_for([@profile, @appointment], :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal login-form-container login-form-div' }) do |f| %>
```

You also need to define `@profile` in your method.

```
   def new
     @profile = Profile.find(params[:profile_id])
     @appointment = Appointment.new
   end
```

Answer (score 1):

Url in your form should be smth like this:

```
<%= form_for [@profile, @appointment] do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

`form_for` tries to use existing paths.  You don't have an `appointments_path` but you do have an  `profile_appointments_path`

To use that path, just pass both objects to the `form_for`

```
<%= form_for([@profile, @appointment], :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal login-form-container login-form-div' }) do |f| %>
```

However, this does mean you need to create an  instance variable `@profile` in your `new` method...

```
   def new
     @profile = Profile.find(params[:profile_id])
     @appointment = Appointment.new
   end
```